# Countdown timer with remote server - React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, time, countdowntimer

I have an app that requires countdown timer. Due date comes from my back-end with rest api. I need to coundown remaining time in my react native app. But I can't use smart phone's time. Because user can be in different timezone / country etc. How i can use server's due date response for react native?

Should I send also remaining time in seconds to user? So I can countdown that remaining time every second?

```
https://www.example.com/getDueDate [POST]
```

returns:

`Y-m-d H:i:s` (future) time like `2021-05-20 23:40:40`

If I use classic countdown approach for javascript, I need to use smart phone's time. But I don't want to use that.

NTP server approach can be tricky for react-native side. It just simple counter.

Comment: is your timer syncronous for all the user or perticular user,,,, like all the users will have the same countdown timings???

Comment: All users will have the same countdown @AshwithSaldanha

Comment: u can use sockets or pusher for this implementaion.. start the timer in the backend and send timer info each second

Comment: this way all the users will have the same timing...

Answer (score 0):

Why not send both the server's current time and the due date? Then start your timer from there?

That being said, the time will still be off by the roundtrip time between your user and the server (which will depend on their internet connection and your server's response time).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible to get time. I'm also using rest api (token base authentication and expiry token after certain time). I'm checking as given below

```
var l_currentDateTimeSeconds;
l_currentDateTimeSeconds=((new  Date().getTime() - "your_time_from_api") / 1000);


if (parseInt(l_CurrentDateTimeSeconds) < parseInt(your_time_from_api))
      {
        //failure case  ;
      }
      else
      {
        //Success case;
      }
```

output of time (in variable) will be in seconds. Visit given below link, it may be help 
https://aboutreact.com/react-native-get-current-date-time/

Comment: you are using smartphone time with `new  Date().getTime()` . It totaly different from my requirements. if / else part only checks phone time < server time. But there are many cases. For example users can set his clock to +3 hours manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is the technique i use and it's really effective.
**Step 1.**
Send due date from server (5pm)
Send current time from server (4pm)

**Step 2.**
Check clients current time (3pm)
Subtract currentTime(server) - currentTime(client) and call it timeOffset

**Step 3.**
setInterval to run every second using the code example below.

```
    //import useState, useEffect from react-native
        
    const [timer,setTimer]=useState();
var serverExpiryDate="'the time the event will expire gotten from server";
        var currentTimeAtServer="the time you got from server via api";

        var currentTimeAtDevice=new Date().getTime();
        const timeOffset= currentTimeAtServer - currentTimeAtDevice;
        //timeOffset is the time difference between the user's clock and the server clock. Calculated when user received response from server.
            
        useEffect(() => {
            let interval = setInterval(() => {
              setTimer(() => {
                let endT = new Date(serverExpiryDate).getTime(); //time from server;
                let nowT = new Date().getTime(); //current time on user've device
                nowT = nowT + timeOffset; //VERY IMPORTANT, helps to sync user's time with server.
                let remaining = endT >= nowT ? Math.floor((endT - nowT) / 1000) : 0;
                let stopCheck = remaining === 0 ? clearInterval(interval) : null;
                return remaining;
              });
            }, 1000); //each count lasts for a second
            return () => {
              clearInterval(interval);
            };
          }, []);
        
        console.log(timer) //this will be decreasing every second
```